# Pass data back to controller from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The structure of my code is I have a parent "component" with a list component inside of that. I want to click edit on an item inside the list component and have that item be passed back to a function in the parent component. The parameter inside the editMember function is being passed back as null

```
let ParentDirective = () => {
    "use strict";
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            visible: '<',
            members: '='
        },
        template: (() => {
            return `
                <div>
                    <div list-directive
                         members="members"
                         edit="methods.editMember(member)">
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;
        })(),
        controller: ($scope) => {
            $scope.methods = {
                editMember: (member) => {
                    console.log(member) //member is null
                }
            };
        }
    }
};

export default {directive: ParentDirective, name: 'parent'};



let ListDirective = () => {
    "use strict";
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            members: '<',
            editMember: '&edit'
        },
        template: (() => {
            return `
                <div>

                    <div ng-repeat="member in members">
                        {{member.name}}
                                <button type="button"
                                        ng-click="editMember(member)">
                                    <i class="ion-edit"></i>
                                </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            `;
        })(),
        controller: ($scope) => {
           }
    }
};

export default {directive: ListDirective, name: 'list'};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use `EventEmitter` to interact between child and parent components in case you are using Angular 2.

Have a look at [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent) for more info on how to do it.

If you are using Angular 1 you're on the write track, just change `ng-click="editMember(member)"` to `ng-click="editMember({member: member})"` since you need to pass it as a hash:

```
<button type="button"
    ng-click="editMember({member: member})">
    <i class="ion-edit"></i>
</button>
```

Note that you need to call it whatever you named your argument in the parent, e.g. if you defined your parent like this:

```
edit="methods.editMember(temp)"
```

Then you should pass it like:

```
<button type="button"
    ng-click="editMember({temp: member})">
    <i class="ion-edit"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! The hash was the missing piece